# Android ListView PaintFlags

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a ListView that a user can click that will set the text of the clicked cell to have its paint flags set to Strikethrough. However, if the user clicks it again, the strikethrough should be removed. Now the bug is that it is being removed, but it is removing all of the style from it and the resulting text looks jagged and skeleton like.

Here is what is happening:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now, what I am doing is to set the strikethrough with

```
((TextView)view).setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

And to remove it, i do:

```
((TextView)view).setPaintFlags( ((TextView)view).getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Removing the paint flag completely removes everything from it, is this intended, or is there a different way of removing only the strikethrough flag?